# Two consecutive rows into a table from one form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, email, mysqli

i have a little problem with a form that must send a picture into a specific folder, and then store the picture name along with other details such as name, email, phone, password into a database.

All work well, with a little problem, when i send my form, in the database there are 2 different rows with different ids, in the first row all the fields are empty except the md5 password field, and on the secound row are all the fields with all the info that i've send into the database. Below i've put the code that i'm using.

```
 $target = "../uploads/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 

 $name = $_POST['name']; 
 $email = $_POST['email']; 
 $telefon = $_POST['telefon'];
 $password = md5($_POST['password']); 
 $photo = ($_FILES['photo']['name']);

 $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO imobiliare_agenti (id, name, email, telefon,    password, photo) VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$email', '$telefon', md5('$password'), '$photo')") ; 

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
{ 

 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded,    and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 

 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In php you have added

```
$password = md5($_POST['password']);
```

Again in query you have added mysql md5 function.

"INSERT INTO imobiliare_agenti (id, name, email, telefon,    password, photo) VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$email', '$telefon', **md5('$password')**, '$photo')"

Try removing one of the md5 functions.

Comment: If i remove one of the md5 functions as you said, for example md5('$password') replacing with '$password' - now i have 6 or 7 rows put into my table. But i must mention that the problem i have it was before i've enter the password field and code. :)

Comment: The problem is because of the ID - if i delete the id field from database and execute the form again, it works well, but i just need my id field. :)